# YII: UTF8 encoding not working?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, yii

I have scraped data from a website. This data is placed in a database. When I print the data:

```
print $row->description;
```

It comes out looking like this:

```
â€¢ Shoot great photos in low light with bright lensâ€¢
```

I was previously able to fix this by adding:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

I've now tried adding this to index.php of YII, but the output doesn't change. I've also tried:

```
$decoded = utf8_decode($row->description);
print $decoded;
```

But then I get:

```
�?� Shoot great photos in low light with bright lens�?�
```

How can I get this to work in YII?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Are you sure your DB is in `utf8` and `utf8_general_ci` ? Try CREATE DATABASE `test` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

Comment: Yii works flawlessly with utf8, problem is with database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following these steps

[How to set up Unicode](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/16/how-to-set-up-unicode/)

[Error with UTF8 characters and htmlspecialchars in yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988123/error-with-utf8-characters-and-htmlspecialchars-in-yii)