# How to encoding utf8 in yii2

Tags: php, utf-8, yii2

I am learning yii2, I have issue for display utf8 in page main.php 
this is error.

```
LO?I S?N PH?M
```

I have used

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

but issue is not solved

Please help me fix it.

Thank you so much

Comment: Does this help at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988123/error-with-utf8-characters-and-htmlspecialchars-in-yii

Comment: I've read it, but my php file more UTF8 string. I do not use utf8_endcode for each string. I want to make one for all strings

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a long time with the same problem.
In my case I used Eclipse for php, and the encoding parameter for all my files was different from utf-8. I had to change the properties of my environment so my code files themselves where utf-8!