# htmlentities, htmlspecialchars, and "invalid multibyte sequence"

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars) tells me

> htmlentities is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.

Sounds like htmlentities is the one I want.

Then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803951/htmlspecialchars-invalid-multibyte-sequence-in-argument) tells me I need the "UTF-8" argument to get rid of this error:

```
Invalid multibyte sequence in argument
```

So, here is my encoding wrapper function (to normalise behaviour across different PHP versions)

```
function html_entities ($s)
{
    return htmlentities ($s, ENT_COMPAT /* ENT_HTML401 */, "UTF-8");
}
```

I am still getting the "multibyte sequence in argument" error.

Here is a sample string which triggers the error, and it's hex encoding:

> Jigue à Baptiste

```
4a 69 67 75 65 20 e0 20 - 42 61 70 74 69 73 74 65
```

I notice that the à is encoded as 0xe0 but as a **single byte** which is above 0x80.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I love those *"What am I doing wrong?"* questions, because the answer is so simple: *Something!*

Comment: Also you're not doing anything wrong. You pass a string into a function that refuses it to process it and you get an error message about that. That's not wrong but right, because the string you pass in there is not correct. It would be really wrong, if you would actually get your undefined but expected result. So what are you doing wrong? *"You have the wrong expectations, that's all."* So what did you expect that function to do and why?

Answer (score 2):

Your string is encoded in ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8. Plain and simple.

```
function html_entities ($s)
{
    return htmlentities ($s, ENT_COMPAT /* ENT_HTML401 */, "ISO-8859-1");
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `à` is encoded as `0xE0` then you didn't save the file in UTF-8 encoding. `0xE0` is invalid UTF-8. It should be `0xC3 0xA0`

Save your file in UTF-8 encoding. Also see [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

If you saved it correctly in utf-8, the hex should look like so:

```
4A 69 67 75 65 20 C3 A0 20 42 61 70 64 69 73 74 65
J  i  g  u  e     à        B  a  p  t  i  s  t  e
```