# Whoops error in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, whoops

Most of the time i am getting

```
"htmlspecialchars() [<a href='function.htmlspecialchars'>function.htmlspecialchars</a>]: Invalid multibyte sequence in argument"
```

in laravel even for syntax error. I didnt understand and I am unable to track the actual error.

How can i track the actual error in laravel 4

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a encoding issue. Be sure to specify the encoding UTF-8 :

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803951/htmlspecialchars-invalid-multibyte-sequence-in-argument)